# Python TFlearn - Loss too high

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, tflearn

After fixing my problem of shape of input I ran my program, the problem is that the total loss printed by the program is way too high (if I compare it for example to the one from the quickstart tutorial).

My goal is to predict the congestion of future entry by using past data (I have more than 10M of entry with the score tagged on) so I shouldn't have problem with training.

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import tflearn

# Load CSV file, indicate that the first column represents labels
from tflearn.data_utils import load_csv
data, labels = load_csv('nowcastScaled.csv', has_header=True, n_classes=2)

# Preprocessing function
def preprocess(data):
    return np.array(data, dtype=np.float32)

# Preprocess data
data = preprocess(data)

# Build neural network
net = tflearn.input_data(shape=[None, 2])
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 32)
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 32)
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 2, activation='linear')
data = np.reshape(data, (-1, 2))
labels = np.reshape(labels, (-1, 2))
net = tflearn.regression(net, optimizer='adam', learning_rate=0.001,
                         loss='categorical_crossentropy')

# Define model
model = tflearn.DNN(net)
# Start training (apply gradient descent algorithm)
model.fit(data, labels, n_epoch=15, batch_size=16, show_metric=True)

# Training
model.save('test_Model')
model.load('test_Model')
score = model.evaluate(data, labels, batch_size=16)
```

My excel file have this kind of look (2 column, 100 000 lignes)

```
calculed_at , congestion
1 , 56
2 , 21
```

This is what the results look like (15 epoch):

```
Training samples: 50000
Validation samples: 0
....
--
Training Step: 40625  | total loss: 15.27961 | time: 17.659s
| Adam | epoch: 013 | loss: 15.27961 - acc: 0.7070 -- iter: 50000/50000
--
Training Step: 43750  | total loss: 15.66268 | time: 17.549s
| Adam | epoch: 014 | loss: 15.66268 - acc: 0.7247 -- iter: 50000/50000
--
Training Step: 46875  | total loss: 15.94696 | time: 18.037s
| Adam | epoch: 015 | loss: 15.94696 - acc: 0.7581 -- iter: 50000/50000
--
```

Have you an idea about what could cause such high loss? It seem strange since the accuracy printed doesn't seem too bad. Thank you for your help.

**Edit**: It seemed to be a good moment when I took theses values since when I tried just now I had total loss exceeding 280 (and an accuracy below 0,3 or barely above).

Comment: would you mind sharing the csv file to debug?

Comment: One thing that strikes my mind immediately is that this is a fully linear network. If you look at the tflearn API, your activation defaults to `linear`. Change it to a nonlinearity first and see if it works.

Also, since this is a regression, why is your loss `categorical_crossentropy`? Elaborating more on your `data` and `labels` would help.

Comment: @jkschin I'm not too used to tflearn, I tried "softmax" instead of linear but it wasn't better. For categorical_crossentropy I used it because it was on the quickstart tutorial and I don't know on what basis I should chose one or another. What do you mean by elaborating more on data and labels?

Comment: Give a few examples of how `data` and `labels`. Elaborate more on "your excel file has this kind of look".

Comment: @jkschin the file can be found [here](https://www.mediafire.com/?wo36nt1e7vo6mqy) with all the information. I uploaded it on mediafire since I didn't knon what was the way to handle fire in SO.

Comment: You're feeding the "ID" of your data into the neural network. Why would you be doing that (unless it's time series)? If that's the case, I'm guessing you want to do some kind of polynomial regression.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148014/discussion-between-eric-godard-and-jkschin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For time series, you construct the input/output samples by considering frames of time  window. In each window if the samples are `{0, 1, ...N}` select the first `N-1` samples as input and the last sample  as output. Then you can do regression to do `time prediction`.